# calc() in Safari for left

Tags: css, safari, css-calc

I  center a div within another one by using calc() function. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and even in IE but in Safari this method doesn't work.

Any suggestions without a javascript fixation?

```
left: -webkit-calc(50% - 25px);
left: -moz-calc(50% - 25px);
left: calc(50% - 25px);
```

Comment: `calc()` expression is supported in Safari 6 and above (`-webkit` prefix is needed for v6.x). It doesn't work in earlier versions of Safari.

Comment: OK thanks, than I should prefer to use something like left: 48% first as a fallback and than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hashem said, it doesn't work in earlier versions of safari.

http://caniuse.com/calc

However if you just want to center the div, a couple ideas come to mind.

One, you could give the container a

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 50%;
```

Or make the width whatever you like.

Second, you could give the parent div

```
text-align:center;
```

Make the child div

```
display: inline-block;
```

and/or set a width for the child div.